# Ion-input loses focus while using bluetooth keyboard

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-keyboard

I am working on entering text with Hardware keyboard(Bluetooth connected) connected to iPhone(iOS 9 and iOS 10) in Ionic 3. While entering, The input is losing its focus and even if i try to enter again, It is not taking any input from keyboard. This hardware keyboard is working well in Android phone but not in iOS.

I tried upgrading/re-installing updated keyboard plugin from Cordova. But no luck with that.

The below is my Ionic Info.

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

Global Packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
```

Local Packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.1.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
Node       : v7.4.0
npm        : 5.0.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

If any ideas, Please let me know. Thank you.

EDIT

I tried with downgrading Ionic from 3.12 to 2.18. Still no luck. Input field still looses focus within milliseconds.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Keyboard plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/).
In **app.components.ts** 's constructor :

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
   keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that need to be verified here , issue you are facing is something that is related to the `WebViews` especially for the `iOS` , so let's start from the Keyboard, try to install the `ionic-plugin-keyboard`

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard --save
```

if you need more events related to how you want to trigger the Keyboard events refer the [official doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard)

i generally use the `ionic-wkwebview` rather than going with the in build webview of iOS which resolves most of the problem. You can install the plugin as follows:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview --save
```

For complete installation refer the [ionic-wkwebview-official doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview)

Even for the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` , there was issue with the `ion-input` but it was resolved and issue is not with the plugin but with the `Webview`,

Here is the reference to that [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/274) which got resolved .

Comment: thanks for the answer. Tried with webview plugin, still same issue.

Comment: @ThePCWizard did you tried installing the ionic key board also?